# Linear Combinations of Numba jitted functions in nopython mode

Tags: python, numba

I've been trying to do some auto generation / jit of functions using numba.

You can call other jit functions from within a jit function, so it's easy to hard code in the functionality I want if you have a specific set of functions like so:

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def f1(x):
    return (x - 2.0)**2

@jit(nopython=True)
def f2(x):
    return (x - 5.0)**2

def hardcoded(x, c):
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def f(x):
        return c[0] * f1(x) + c[1] * f2(x)
    return f

lincomb = hardcoded(3, (0.5, 0.5))
print(lincomb(2))

Out: 4.5
```

However, say you don't know ahead of time what the f1, f2 are. I'd like to be able to use a factory to generate the functions, and then have another to generate linear combinations thereof:

```
def f_factory(x0):
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def f(x):
        return (x - x0)**2
    return f

def linear_comb(funcs, coeffs, nopython=True):
    @jit(nopython=nopython)
    def lc(x):
        total = 0.0
        for f, c in zip(funcs, coeffs):
            total += c * f(x)
        return total
    return lc
```

And call it at runtime. This works without nopython mode:

```
funcs = (f_factory(2.0), f_factory(5.0))
lc = linear_comb(funcs, (0.5, 0.5), nopython=False)
print(lc(2))

Out: 4.5
```

But not with nopython mode.

```
lc = linear_comb(funcs, (0.5, 0.5), nopython=True)
print(lc(2))

TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'funcs': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'tuple'>
File "<ipython-input-100-2d3fb6214044>", line 11
```

So it looks like numba has trouble with tuples of jit functions. Is there any way to get this behavior to work?

The set of functions and c's can get large so I would really like to get this to compile in nopython mode.

Comment: Any reason not to make `x0` a parameter to `f` and remove the factor?

Comment: In real code, the f can be more arbitrary. If x0 is a parameter for the function, then the linear combination needs to know the parameters to each f, which may be diffferent. I'd like to be able to say, have f(x, x0, alpha, beta) and f2(x, x0, bool_flag) for example, and have closures encapsulating so they appear to be f(x)

Comment: Got it, I think you may be out luck with current numba limitations, short of doing some very ugly code gen.

Comment: I feared as much. Is there perhaps a way to generate names for the jitted functions, then codegen a function calling them by name or something? It wouldn't be the worst thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but as a hacky workaround, you could indeed use some "templating" to generate a unique name and call of each function in the tuple.

```
def linear_comb(funcs, coeffs, nopython=True):
    scope = {'coeffs': coeffs}

    stmts = [
    'def lc(x):',
    '    total = 0.0',
    ]
    for i, f in enumerate(funcs):
        # give each function a unique name
        scope[f'_f{i}'] = f
        # codegen for total line
        stmts.append(f'    total += coeffs[{i}] * _f{i}(x)')
    stmts.append('    return total')

    code = '\n'.join(stmts)
    exec(code, scope)
    lc = jit(nopython=nopython)(scope['lc'])
    return lc

lc = linear_comb(funcs, (0.5, 0.5), nopython=True)

lc(2)
Out[103]: 4.5
```

Comment: Nice! This works for me. I had tried to figure something like this out but didn't think to leverage exec in this way. Neato.